# Google sheet: Get the date in correct format

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am having one google sheet which contains date. While fetching it, it shows 7/4/2018 as 43285 in javascript.

I want to show date as it is. How can I do it?

Thank you,
Trupti

Comment: try TO_DATE(43285)

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript [Date Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to work with time then use the snippets from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44062122)

```
function convertEpochToSpecificTimezone(offset){
    var d = new Date(1495159447834);
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);  //This converts to UTC 00:00
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    return nd.toLocaleString();
}
```

and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc) as code reference.

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc =  Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),
 date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());

 return new Date(now_utc);
```